# Capture STDOUT from included file to variable

Tags: php

How to capture everything what leaves included file to variable or another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output buffering is the way to go.

```
<?php

ob_start(); // Start buffering output

include '/path/to/file/';

$myVariable = ob_get_clean(); // Put the buffered output
                              // into $myVariable and clear
                              // the output buffer
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

Comment: **IMPORTANT!:** this way OutputBuffering stays ON - to JUST turn it off (no output) I recommend using `ob_end_clean();` ... see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php for more info :)

Answer (score 0):

Using output buffers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php