# Saving the result of an included PHP script as a variable

Tags: php, variables, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture STDOUT from included file to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451287/capture-stdout-from-included-file-to-variable)

OKAY, perhaps this isn't worded as well as it could be...

This is what I want to do: I want to include the resulting source code of an executed PHP file into another PHP file, so that it can be manipulated and reused. The resulting output needs to incorporate the values of several $_GET variables, and the to-be-included PHP file's execution is dependent upon their values. So I need the resulting source code (what you'd see when you go to "View Source" in your browser) of a file like: "index.php?page=1&id=1&etc=something" to be included into another PHP file ... any thoughts?

---

Is there a way to include a PHP file, and then save the result of that file's execution into a variable in the PHP file that included it, so as to be further used? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: Downvoted as as tiresome repeat that results from not doing a search first and for not correctly describing the problem which, according to comments below, was to capture the output of the included file.

Comment: Blame Google for not finding anything useful on this site or any other. Next time I'll search here directly. Simmer down.

Comment: I suppose it is not Google but someone's search skill...

Answer (score 6):

```
ob_start();
include "your_script.php";
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

That's it. But there should be no definition of the constants or functions already defined in the calling script. To prevent the change of the variables this code could be inside of the function's body, so that variables from 'your_script.php' will be defined in the local scope of that function.  Another way is to perform a http request

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://your_server/script.php');
```

or even (if you are using Apache and php as module)

```
ob_start();
virtual("/webpath_from_server_root/your_script.php");
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

In that case 'your_script.php' will not interfere with constants and functions of the main script.

Comment: Worked splendidly, thank you!

Comment: +1000000 (if I could) for *not* using parentheses with `include`

Comment: Actually ... while that works great for a file called, say 'index.php,' if I attach anything to that (say, 'index.php?page=1&id=1,' for example), neither include, nor virtual, nor file_get_contents is successful in including the resulting output ... any thoughts?

Comment: @Phil ... because include is a language construct and not a function? That's my best layperson guess as to why you'd be so very generous in your up-voting :)

Comment: @MattPayne  `anything to that` adding GET parameters should work for `virtual` and `file_get_contents`. For the `include` you have to 'define' those variables in the script. Like `$_GET['page'] = 1;` and so on before the inclusion. `include` works with filesystem of the server and 'knows' nothing about parameters in the way you are trying to transfer them.

Comment: That was it ... just needed to use the full URL to get it to work with file_get_contents. Thanks!

Comment: @MattPayne  and one more advice.. if you are going to use `file_get_contents` with URL wrappers ('http' part in the example above) somewhere else - it could be not allowed to perform this connection (especially at free hosting) by security reasons.

Comment: Well, I thought I had the answer, but ... nothing but a blank page is the result. No errors or anything, just a complete lack of what I was trying to grab with file_get_contents ... any other thoughts?

Comment: -1 just to justify that feast of bad design

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include_once("your script");    
$result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// now $result has anything that was output from the inclusion of "your script"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the output control function @PHP [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  include( 'yourscript.php' );
  $cache= ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```